# URL.openstream() method can't read from link with &

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, url

I have a link to a .csv which looks like this:

> http://website.com/data.csv?since=2019-03-21T00:00Z&sensor=xxx

My method get this link as URL

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(URL.openStream()));
```

The problem is that it is not properly downloading .csv. I have realized that if I add 'amp;' after & it works properly. Is there any easy way to work this out?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/

```
public URL getFinalUrl(URL url) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
        conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

        boolean redirect = false;

        int status = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                    || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                    || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
                redirect = true;
        }
        String newUrl = null;
        if (redirect) {
            // get redirect url from "location" header field
            newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");

            // get the cookie if need, for login
            String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

            // open the new connnection again
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
            conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
            conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");
        }
        System.out.println(newUrl);
        return new URL(newUrl);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Wrong sensor URL");
    }
    return null;
}
```